# Why is my web page created along with flask getting refreshed every time I click the submit button

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am creating a flask program which generates a certain number of passwords depending on the user's demand. The user gets the freedom of editing the password. The source code is mentioned below.

**Password_creator.py**

```
from random import *
from itertools import *
import string
class password_generator():  
   def __init__(self,final_output,special_nproduction,final_specp): #creating the local variables
       self.final_output = final_output
       self.special_nproduction = special_nproduction
       self.final_specp = final_specp
      
      
   def alpha_rand_func(self): #for randomly selecting alphabets
       alpha = string.ascii_letters
       for i in range(4):
           self.final_output += choice(alpha)
        
   def symbol_rand_func(self): #for randomly selecting symbols
      symbol = string.punctuation
      for i in range(3):
         self.special_nproduction += choice(symbol)
             
   def int_rand_func(self): #for randomly selecting integers
      integer = string.digits
      for i in range(2):
         self.special_nproduction += choice(integer)
        
   def special_number_production(self): #for concatenating the integers and symbols
          self.special_nproduction = list(self.special_nproduction)
          init_perm = list(permutations((self.special_nproduction),5))
          selected_comb_init_list = choice(init_perm) #selecting a permutation of integers and symbols randomly
          mod_selected_comb_init = "" #for storing the permutation in the form of a variable
          for i in selected_comb_init_list: #iterating through the selected_comb_init_list
             mod_selected_comb_init += i 
          self.final_output += mod_selected_comb_init  # adding the integer-symbol combination to final output
   def final_output_production(self): #for concatenating all the characters, selecting a combination of it randommly and returning it as output
           return self.final_output #returns the final output
####################################          

####################################
```

**exec_prog.py**

```
from Password_creator import *
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,redirect,url_for
from table import Table
from flask_modus import Modus
app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='template')
modus= Modus(app)
@app.route("/")
def data_reveal(): # for user input for suggestions
    return render_template('input.html')

@app.route('/data-extract') # for extracting the user input
def data_extract():
    global sug
    sug = int(request.args.get('sug')) # to get the user input
    return redirect('/generate') # redirecting to generate
@app.route('/generate') # for generating the passwords
def generate():
    global final_g
    global data_x
    global password
    final_g = [] # for the passwords
    password = []
    for i in range(sug):
     v =  password_generator("","","") #for calling the class
     alpha_g = v.alpha_rand_func()    # line 25- 30; please refer the Password_creator.py file                 
     sym_g = v.symbol_rand_func()
     int_g = v.int_rand_func()
     spec_g = v.special_number_production()     
     final = v.final_output 
     final_g.append(v.final_output)
     passwd_obj = Table(v.final_output,'nil') # for storing them in a class 
     password.append(passwd_obj) # for storing them in a list
    print(final_g) 
    
    return render_template('output_disp.html',final_lst = password) # rendering the output_disp.html

###############
@app.route('/generate/<int:id>',methods = ["GET","PATCH","POST"]) # for modifying the function
def show(id):
     found  =  next(entry for entry in password if entry.id == id) # for finding the entry with the required entry
     if request.method  == b"PATCH": # for dealing with PATCH 
        found.passwd = request.form['edit_passwd']
        return redirect('/generate')
     return render_template('modify.html',found_entry = found)
    

@app.route('/generate/<int:id>/edit',methods = ["GET","PATCH","POST"]) # for showing the function
def modify(id):
    found  =  next(entry for entry in password if entry.id == id)
    return render_template('modify.html',found_entry = found)
###############
```

**modify.html**

```
{% extends 'str_main.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div id  = "modify-div">
<form id = "edit" action = "{{url_for('show',id  = found_entry.id)}}?_method=PATCH" method ="POST">
   <input type = "text" value = "{{found_entry.passwd}}" name = "edit_passwd">
   <input type ="submit" value = "save change" >
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**output_disp.html**

```
{% extends 'str_main.html'%}
{% block content%}
<div id  =  "options">
  <div id  = "btn-output-1"><h6>Upload file</h6></div>
  <div id  = "btn-output-2"><h6>Main page</h6></div>
  <div id  = "btn-output-3"><h6>Save</h6></div> 
</div>
<div id = "output-head">
  <h1>Here are the suggestions</h1>
</div>
<div id  = "output-div">  
  <form id = "output-data" method = "POST">   
    <table>
         <tr>
           <th>Password</th>
           <th>Description</th>
         </tr>
         
         {% for i in final_lst %}
        <tr>    
           <td> <a href ="#">{{ i.passwd }}</a></td> 
           <td>{{ i.desc }}</td>
        </tr>     
         {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <input type = "text" value = "fileName" name = "fileName">
    <button type ="button" value= "saving file">Saving fhile</button>
  </form>
</div>   

{% endblock %}
```

**table.py**

```
class Table(): #class for storing the passwords with their description
    count  = 1
    def __init__(self,passwd,desc):
        self.passwd = passwd
        self.desc = desc
        self.id = Table.count
        Table.count += 1
```

Here is the github repository URL
https://github.com/OCTRACORE/cs_Project

The problem is that whenever I go to the `/generate/<int:id>/edit` route and try to edit the password, I don't see the change in `output_disp.html`. Instead ,the page gets refreshed and I see a new set of suggestion.
So what can I do inorder to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after looking through you code I think I figured out your issue.

However I want to say there is a lot of bad practices in your code. One of the biggest ones is using globals in a web app. You should never do this. If you plan to run multiple instances of this app to handle more requests then the other instances will not have access to other instances globals so you will have many bugs that will be difficult to trace down.

Anyways the issue I see in your `generate` function.

When you submit a change to the password it does get saved. But that save is completely destroyed because in your `generate` function you don't check for previous passwords you also have no way of knowing if something did change or if you really do want to generate a new set of passwords.

My advice

- Learn the proper setup and structure for a web app.
- Don't use globals ever in a web app. Too many bugs will come from this and will be a pain to find.
- Your app looks like it will just be a normal web app with no javascript or ajax, so don't use PATCH or DELETE for form methods. Use GET and POST and use differing urls to decide how to handle those requests.

If there's not a good tutorial out there for flask on how to setup endpoints/urls for your app, then look at the setup for Django projects. Flask mimics Django in a lot of ways on how it handles endpoints/urls.

Comment: Is there any way for not implementing the function after editing the password?

Comment: I have used global because I want to access certain variables from other functions too.

Comment: Sure you can add an if statement to decide to run that function or not but the real issue is how do you know when/what to check when you run that endpoint of generate. One way you can do this is have a url `/generate/new` to generate a new set and a url `/show` to show currently saved ones. `/generate/<id>/edit` to edit a password.

I understand why your using globals but it is bad practice to do so. If this is just for practice/testing then you can leave the globals but if not you need to replace those globals with a class that you can call to handle saving and retrieving those values.

Comment: I did the following and it really worked out. I realized that before, the program used to get refreshed every time I used to click the save-changes button, so the modifications used to get overwritten.

Comment: Awesome, well it sounds like you got it working. I'm glad to hear. Keep going and you'll start to learn more about web app and how they work when it comes to python web apps. If my comments helped out please give me a upvote and mark this question as answered.